# Table or view doesn't exist when DBlink is wrong

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g

If I run the below query, I'm getting **ORA-02019 connection description for remote database not found** as the DBlink **BLAH** is not there.

```
SELECT * FROM DUAL@BLAH;
```

But if I put it in an anonymous block, its giving **ORA-00942 table or view does not exist** error.

```
BEGIN
  SELECT * FROM DUAL@BLAH;
EXCEPTION
  WHEN OTHERS THEN
    NULL;
END;
```

Comment: remove the WHEN OTHERS THEN NULL and show us the output when you run the block

Answer (score 0):

Try this (Dynamic SQL), you would get `ORA-02019 connection description for remote database not found`

```
begin
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'select * from dual@blah';
end;
/
```

The other error `ORA-00942 table or view does not exist` is probably a `compilation` error and not a *runtime* error.

Reason for the compilation error is, `blah` is unknown to oracle during the `semantic` checks on compilation since it is not defined (synonyms).

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that ORA-02019  is run time error. The SQL is try to run the table at dblink but fails. That's why ORA-02019  occurred. While the ORA-00942  is compile time error. While compilation of begin..end block it is validating the objects. Validation failed and it has thrown the ORA-00942.